# if condition is true, replace the image php 5 cakephp

Tags: php, image, cakephp

is it possible to replace an image with another image when a condition is true?

```
 $img= $this->Html->image('squareBlue.png', 
     array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100')
 );
 echo $img;
 if($x == 1)
 {
   $img= $this->Html->image('suareRed.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
   echo $img;
 }
```

### what my code does is they display both images instead of replacing them? how can I make the replacement possible? Thanks !

okay, maybe my initial question was not what I want to do in the first place (silly me).. :p

actually what I want to do is like this, I have these sequence of blue squares displayed with one red square initially placed  at the front of blue square sequence, so each time a user clicks a button I want the red square to move to the right replacing the first blue image. Here is my code:

```
for ($y = 0; $y < 11; $y++) {
 for ($x = 0; $x < 15; $x++) { 
    ${'img' . $x . $y} = $this->Html->image(
        'squareBlue.png', 
        array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' =>  '1', 
             'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 
             'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100')
     );
     echo ${'bg' . $x . $y};
}    
    echo '<br />'; 
}
```

then if button clicked, say the coordinate $img  is changed to $x = 2 and $y = 0;

```
   $cx = 2;
   $cy = 0;
   echo ${'bg' . $cx . $cy} = $this->Html->image('squareRed.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
```

Sorry if my question is confusing...

Comment: Just echo after `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

Ahem, use double = to check a var.
Before checking be sure to have something like

```
$x = myvalue;
```

After setted we can check the var.

```
if($x == 1)
 {
   $img= $this->Html->image('suareRed.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
   echo $img;
 } else {
$img= $this->Html->image('squareBlue.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
 echo $img;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Let me simplify your code:

You just need to change the image name with `if else`. No other change.

Then why are you writting the image generating code twice?

Use a ternary operator to determine which image name to be displayed depending upon the condition.

```
$imgName = ($x = 1) ? 'suareRed.png' : 'squareBlue.png';
$img= $this->Html->image($imgName, array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
echo $img;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add else

```
 $img= $this->Html->image('squareBlue.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));

 if($x = 1)
 {
   $img= $this->Html->image('suareRed.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
    'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
   echo $img;
 }else{
   echo $img;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both images are displayed because you are using `echo` twice.

Also try to reduce your code to something like that:

```
 $fileName = 'squareBlue.png';
 if ($x = 1) {
     $fileName = 'suareRed.png';
 }

 echo $this->Html->image($fileName, array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '1', 
      'height' => '60', 'width' => '60', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100'));
```

It's easier to read and you are calling method `image` only once.